# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded with a counter

Tags: python, class, recursion

From an old example, I tried to insert a counter member to the class Point but when I run, it won't evaluate with Error: **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded!**. However, I didn't have such impression this error happened years ago with earlier Python version.

**EDIT:** the line *id=0* was an mistaken.

```
import math
class Point():
#           id=0
            def __init__(self, x, y, z:float=0):
                import sys; print(f"{self.id=}>{sys.getrecursionlimit()}")# maximum recursion depth 1000 exceeded
                self._x = x; self._y = y; self._z = z; self.id+=1
            @property
            def x(self):
                return self._x
            @x.setter# to define a "non-public member"
            def x(self, value):
               self._x=value
            @property
            def y(self):
                return self._y
            @y.setter
            def y(self, value):
               self._y=value
            @property
            def xy(self):
                return [self._x,self._y]
            @xy.setter
            def xy(self,xval,yval):
               self._x=xval;self._y=yval
            @property
            def z(self):
                return self._z
            @z.setter
            def z(self, value):
                self._z=value
            @property
            def id(self):
                return self.id
#    @id.setter
#    def id(self, value): # raise AttributeError("Can't")
#        raise WriteCoordinateError("Point Number id is read-only")
            @property
            def distance(self):
                return round(math.dist((0, 0, 0), (self._x, self._y, self._z)))
```

Comment: What does your `id` property return?

Comment: when you try to return `self.id` you need to get that property and so you call `id()` and that tries to return `self.id` and to do so it tries to get that value by calling `id()`....

Comment: Does the traceback show the failing line? You should include it (or at least part) in the question.

Comment: As an aside, there is no reason for getters/setters here. Since they don't process the values, all they do is make the code slower.

Answer (score 1):

As JonSG said, this is because you have mutiple definitions of id. On top of your class, you say: `id=0`. But at the end, you define the property id (which can now be referred as `self.id`) as a function that returns `self.id`. because `self.id` is a property again, a function is called named `self.id()`, which returns itself.

hopefully it is now clear to you why this happens, but I will give one more example:

```py
def f(x):
    return f(x)
```

this is sort of what your function does.

you could name the private `id` to `_id` and `return self._id`.

your code becomes than:

```py
class Point() # These brackets are redunant, do you want to put something in later?
    _id = 0
    ...
    ...
    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id
```